# Server giving out unsual network activity

Tags: php, apache, cpanel

I'm looking for some to find out why our server is having this issue.

We got a notification from our server provider that our server was giving out unusual network activity. I've tried to dig through the logs but getting nothing.

We had a WP User that had a bunch of hijacked files in their public_html. I went through and deleted all these files and ran a security check.

Here is some of the logs from the server provider:

```
[Wed Apr 25 17:19:59.239790 2018] [:error] [pid 14971:tid 
140081856567040] [client 212.48.71.168:37282] [client 212.48.71.168] 
ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Operator GT matched 
0 
at USER:bf_block. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec/modsec2.user.conf"] 
[line "13"] [id "10014"] [msg "ip address blocked for 15 minutes, more 
than 
10 login attempts in 3 minutes."] [hostname "tyler.provick.ca"] [uri 
"/wp- 
login.php"] [unique_id "WuD-DaXgQ8dmu2ilwH6qhAAAAAE"]
[Wed Apr 25 17:20:05.749244 2018] [:error] [pid 23881:tid 
140081846077184] 
[client 212.48.71.168:37994] [client 212.48.71.168] ModSecurity: Access 
denied with code 406 (phase 2). Operator GT matched 0 at USER:bf_block. 
[file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec/modsec2.user.conf"] [line "13"] [id 
"10014"] [msg "ip address blocked for 15 minutes, more than 10 login 
attempts in 3 minutes."] [hostname "tyler.provick.ca"] [uri "/wp- 
login.php"] [unique_id "WuD-FWAM7JcmpgzC2BGdCAAAAMI"]
```

I've tried things like:

```
[root@pluto ~]# grep ModSecurity /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log | sed 
-e 's#^.*\[id "\([0-9]*\).*hostname "\([a-z0-9\-\_\.]*\)"\].*uri "#\1 
\2 #' | cut -d\" -f1 | sort -n | uniq -c | sort –n
sort: cannot read: –n: No such file or directory
[root@pluto ~]# grep -i modsec /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log | grep 
clientexec | grep 2014 | sed "s/$/\\n/"
```

And updated the Kernal:

```
[root@pluto ~]# yum -y update kernel
```

**Server is Centos 7, with Cloud Linux, Cagefs & cPanel etc.**

[root@pluto ~]# tail /usr/local/apache/logs/access_log

```
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:10:59:43 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:10:59:50 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:10:59:57 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:10:59:58 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:10:59:59 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:11:00:00 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2018:11:00:01 +0100] "GET /whm-server-status 
HTTP/1.0" 200 17088 "-" "-"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:11:00:01 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
::1 - - [27/Apr/2018:11:00:03 +0100] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" 
"Apache/2.4.33 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2o mod_bwlimited/1.4 
Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8 (internal dummy connection)"
127.0.0.1 - - [27/Apr/2018:11:00:06 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0\n" 400 10072 
"-" "-"
```

Comment: Just looks to me like someone is hacking on a login and getting banned for exceeding the fail limit

Comment: They are but it's coming from our server!?

Comment: Dont suppose you have a penetration test running or something like that?